# Java: singleton from base class

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Lets assume we've got base class:

```
public class Base {
      public Base(int i) {
      /* ... */
      }
      /* ... */
}
```

We want to create singleton based on this class. The problem is that class have public constructor, so extending it will result in singleton having public constructor, too:

```
public class SingletonBase extends Base {
   private static final SingletonBase _instance = new SingletonBase();

   private SingletonBase() {
      super(0);
   }

  public SingletonBase(int i) {  // Want to avoid this!
     super(i) 
  }

  public static void getInstance() {
     return _instance;
  }
  /* ... */       
}
```

Singleton, of course, cannot have public constructors, so we want to avoid this. 
So, what is most elegant way/pattern to have proper Singleton with functionalities from class Base?

Edit: Modifying Base class is prohibited, since it is from an external library.

Comment: Just declare all constructors of your `SingletonBase` as private

Comment: Forgot to mention, I cannot modify base class - it's from external library.

Comment: But SingletonBase can have only one constructor... Just remove the public one and voilla. And why on Earth you use abstracion for Singleton ? If you want to reuse the framework code just use the Base object inside the singleton.

Comment: You could resort to reflection if you cant directly access the source of the base.

Comment: Maybe you can "favor composition over inheritance", by that I mean just keep an instance of `Base` in your Singleton class.
You should keep in mind that with inheritance, every subclass should be able to be used instead of the superclass and making a singleton subclass does not quite fit that.
Maybe think about if you really need a singleton.

Comment: @Kao Please read my comment. I suggested constructors of `SingletonBase`, not `Base` class.

Comment: @kiruwka Yup, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. So just
delete this part and you'll get what you need.

```
public SingletonBase(int i) {  // Want to avoid this!
    super(i) 
}
```

Additionally, you may want to make the `Base` class
abstract so that no one can instantiate it by mistake
by calling the `Base` constructor directly.

```
public abstract class Base {
    public Base(int i) {
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}

public class SingletonBase extends Base {
    private static final SingletonBase _instance = new SingletonBase();

    private SingletonBase() {
        super(0);
    }

    public static SingletonBase getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yup, I don't know why I thought constructors are inherited. Thanks!

Comment: I voted down because if you delete (or better word: omit) a constructor in the subclass the superclass constructor will still be called.

Comment: @ScottShipp You didn't get the question context here, I think.

Comment: The making of class as abstract is a good idea in such cases. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could make `SingletonBase` just a normal subclass and delegate the Singleton-part to a different class.
I don't know what your specific context is, but you would have `Subclass extends Base` and somewhere else you would have your `SingletonContainer` or something like that where you have the method `public static Subclass getInstance()`.

That way, you would have your usual inheritance and also the Singleton effect, since the `SingletonContainer` would be responsible for keeping only a single instance of Subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you inherit from a class that have a public constructor that you have to create the same public constructor, you can do :

```
public class SingletonBase extends Base {
   private static final SingletonBase _instance = new SingletonBase();

   private SingletonBase() {
      super(0);
   }

  public static void getInstance() {
     return _instance;
  }
  /* ... */       
}
```

Or even :

```
public class SingletonBase extends Base {
   private static final SingletonBase _instance = new SingletonBase();

   private SingletonBase() {
      super(0);
   }

  private SingletonBase(int i) {  // Want to avoid this!
     super(i) 
  }

  public static void getInstance() {
     return _instance;
  }
  /* ... */       
}
```